# topology on $\mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: general-topology, analysis

on $\mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{Q}$ we define a bases of open sets for each $(x,x')\in \mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{Q}$ by

$$ \mathcal{B}_{x,x'}=\{(z,y)\in \mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{Q}: \, x<z<x', y\in \mathbb{Q}\}$$

the question is to find $cl(A)$ and $int(A)$ where $$A=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{Q}: x^2+y^2=1\}$$

I don't know how to get it, I don't understand the topology.

Comment: What is $d'$ here?

Comment: @Patrick there is no $d'$ in the context

Comment: @William I correct it it is z

Answer (score 0):

The base is vertical strips of the plane without the edges.
int A is empty, cl A = [-1,1]×Q.

The open sets are U×Q where U is open within Q.
The closed sets are K×Q where K is closed within Q.

Comment: How I can see all this ? @William , please how to get that $\mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{Q}$ is open ? and what are the closed sets?

Comment: @Vrouvrou.  See edit.

Comment: what do you mean by U is open ? and K closed? are intervals ???? I can't draw the open sets in this topology..

Comment: @Vrouvrou.  U is open within Q, U is an open subset of Q.  Can you draw the open set (0,1)×Q?

Comment: but the closes sets have the form $]-\infty,x]\cup[x',+\infty[\times \mathbb{Q}$

Comment: There are a lot more closed sets than those. @Vrouvrou

Comment: but how we know that $[-1,1]\times Q$ is closed? here and why it is the small one which contains A?

Comment: I think that $cl(A)=([-1,1]\cap Q)\times Q$ no?